# tvOS: Is there any API to control navigating the system UI?

Tags: remote-access, tvos, apple-tv

I am attempting to create a tvOS application which can control the Apple TV device (by simulating key presses on the remote for example). I would then be able to connect to a socket in this application to be able to control the Apple TV's main system UI.

I know remote control of Apple TVs is possible with HomeKit or DAAP/DACP, but I am looking *specifically* for an API local to the Apple TV itself.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is at the moment no public API for doing something like that. The only official API to this type of things if via XCUITest, which you can not be of course used to create Apps.

Nevertheless, you can find [here](https://github.com/jeanregisser/mediaremotetv-protocol) the reversed engineered documentation of the private protocol of Siri Remote, and [here](https://medium.com/@evancoleman/apple-tv-meet-my-lights-dissecting-the-media-remote-protocol-d07d1909ad82) an interesting project making use of it.